# Загруженная картинка не отображается в галерее

Tags: java, android

Программа скачивает картинку и сохраняет её в папке Download.

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator
                +Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.separator+ "diagram"
                + strings.getText().toString().replace(',', '_') + ".png");

        try {
            if (!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            outputStream.write(downloadImageTask.getBuff());
            Toast.makeText(this,"Диаграмма сохранена "+f.getPath().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(outputStream!=null){
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Всё сохраняется правильно, но не отображается в галерее. Картинку можно найти только c помощью файлового менеджера. Как сделать, чтобы сохранённые изображения были видны в галерее?

Comment: После перезагрузки устройства сохраненные ранее картинки отображаются в галерее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До меня дошло, что нужно как-то уведомить систему, что появилась новая картинка. Вот как это сделать:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                    new String[]{filePath}, null, null);
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать, как сделать чтобы файл появился в системной папке загрузки. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как можно до такого додуматься))) Плюсую