# Почему созданная папка с изображением не появляется в галерее?

Tags: android, файлы, gallery

Вот код:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = MainActivity.login + "_" + timeStamp;

    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath(), "file_folder");

    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdir();
        Log.e("SD", storageDir.exists() + "");
    }
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    return image;
}
```

С помощью проводника я нашел созданный каталог, и файл(img), но они никак не появляются в галерее.
Пожалуйста, объясните пжл, что нужно сделать, чтобы каталог и фото отображались в галерее.

Comment: Потому что галерея ещё не знает, что что-то где-то появилось, попробуйте ей подсказать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439433/11515

Comment: @woesss, вроде сделал как сказано, но не получилось(. Вот мой код: MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CreateClientActivity.this, new String[]{"/sdcard/DCIM/file_folder/"}, null, null);

Comment: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CreateClientActivity.this, new String[]{ image.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);` - не папку, а файл(ы) ему передайте.

Comment: @woesss, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

В общем поискал и нашел наверное то, что необходимо в этом случае:

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
private File mFile;

public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
    mFile = f;
    mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mMs.connect();
}

@Override
public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
}

@Override
public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    mMs.disconnect();
}

}
```

Где необходимо, после появление новых фото, вызвать:

```
new SingleMediaScanner(this, file);
```

Надеюсь кому нибудь поможет.